# Hibernate database column not found - defined in annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting an exception with hibernate that I can't figure out.

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (role, username) on table user_roles: database column 'role' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)

I have defined the name of the column "role" with the annotation, am I missing something here?

Any help appreciated.

```
  ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames =
{ "role", "username" }) )
public class UserRole
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private Integer userRoleId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 45)
  private String role;

  ...
}
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you happen to use? Does this setting `<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>` make a difference?

Comment: Depending on your database, the name 'role' may be reserved (e.g. Postgres). It could have failed to create the table or may not be quoting it right.

Comment: Thanks - I changed "role" to "`role`" and its working now! I'm using MySQL5.